# Unity windows startup screen not showing anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed **Unity version 2017.1.0f3**. It was working fine till yesterday. Today I was trying to download an asset from asset store. But when I tried opening asset store in unity it was showing unable to connect message even though internet connection was working fine in the other apps. So I searched for it and found that re-installing unity may fix the problem. So I did that but now I am getting another problem.

Unity start up page is showing nothing at all. Generally it  shows list of created projects but for me it is showing nothing.

Here is screenshot for that.
[image]

I have tried enabling/disabling internet when starting unity but that too didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reopen Unity after deleting the "Library" directory.

Comment: I figured out this some ip issue with unity. I tried with a different wifi connection and it was working. But still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Well, deleting Library folder helped me with the exactly same issue, so in case it will happen again, you can try it :)